# Django 2-ModelForm user registration and double submission error

Tags: django, web, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to create a basic user registration system for clients of a web application.

I've created the appropriate views and templates to create a form page which creates a Django User object and a UserProfile object of my own creation. (These are linked via a 1-1 field).

After visiting and filing in the forms on my registration page, I click submit and the fields related to initializing the UserProfile fields will be cleared and a "This field is required." error will be displayed over each input box (despite being properly filled in previously). If I fill these selected fields in again, and press submit the registration request will be processed correctly.

In the terminal, I've printed out the value of is_valid() for each form. On the first pass, the User form returns true, while the UserProfile form returns false. On the second submission they both return true.

Could you help me understand why this second form is returning false on the first pass and forcing me to resubmit?

Code is below:

## models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    institute = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=2500)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password', 'email']

class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ['user']
```

## views.py

```
def registration(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('post')
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, prefix='user')
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, prefix='userprofile')
        print('user form ' + str(user_form.is_valid()))
        print('profile form ' + str(profile_form.is_valid()))
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            print('both valid')
            user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            userprofile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            userprofile.user = user
            userprofile.save()
            print('success')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('registration-success/')
    else:
        print('unbound')
        user_form = UserForm(prefix='user')
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(prefix='profile')
    context = { 'userform': user_form,
                'userprofileform': profile_form,}
    return render(request, 'registration/register.html', context)

def success(request):
    return render(request, 'registration/success.html', )
```

## template.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h2> Registration </h2>


    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{userform}}
    </br></br>
        {{userprofileform}}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
    <a href="password_reset/" id="forgot"> forgot username/password</a><br />
    <a href="register" id="new">new user</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your POST codepath, you have this:

```
    profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, prefix='userprofile')
```

In your else codepath, this:

```
    profile_form = UserProfileForm(prefix='profile')
```

The prefix values need to match so that the POST data will be bound correctly to the profile form.  It works on your resubmission because that goes through the POST codepath, so the ids used in the template match those the form object expects.